# How to mark an issue as resolved from the commit log?

Tags: version-control, bug-tracking, issue-tracking, bitbucket

I noted that in BitBucket when your commit log contains a number like `#12` this number is linked to the bug number 12.

I found this feature interesting, and I wonder if there is any keyword that would allow me to mark the issue as resolved from the commit log instead of going to the web interface each time.

If BitBucket doesn't do it, could you point a system that does?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Code Project Hosting also supports it:

http://code.google.com/p/support/wiki/IssueTracker#Integration_with_version_control

There are commit-log commands to:

1. Easily set an issue's status to Fixed.
2. Update any aspect of the issue, and add a comment.
3. Enter a new issue.
4. Request a code review.

   ```
   (Fixes issue NNN)    Enclose command in parentheses
   Fixes issue NNN.     Full sentence in your log message description
   Fixes issue NNN  On a line by itself
   ```

The word Fixes can replaced with Closes or Resolves. The issue number can have a leading pound-sign (#) or not.

The other commit-log commands use a multi-line "long form" syntax that is more powerful.

```
COMMAND-LINE
ISSUE-FIELD-UPDATE*
COMMENT-TEXT...
```

Where COMMAND-LINE is one of the following:

```
Update issue NNN
New issue
New review
```

There can be any number of ISSUE-FIELD-UPDATE lines. These lines can be one of the following:

```
Summary: NEW-VALUE
Status: NEW-VALUE
Owner: NEW-VALUE
Cc: PLUS-MINUS-LIST
Labels: PLUS-MINUS-LIST
```

Answer (score 102):

Bitbucket already supports marking issues on commit using the [Issues service](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-the-issues-service-223216615.html).

> The issues service scans commit messages for commands which will automatically change the state of the relevant issue on the tracker.
>
> [snip]
>
> Examples:
>
> "... fixes #4711 ..."                  # marks issue as resolved
> "... reopening bug 4711..."            # marks issue as open
> "... refs ticket 4711..."              # links changeset to issue as comment
> "... refs bug #4711 and #4712..."      # links to multiple issues

You may need to activate it, to do so:

> Services can be activated on a per-repository basis by the administrator. Go to your repository page, select the Admin tab, click Services, then select a service from the list, and add it.

Comment: excelent! It seems I forgot to RTFM before posting here. But it is nice also to see what other technologies provide

Comment: More info on supported formats on the commit message here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Bitbucket+Issues+Service

Comment: Seem like the page now lives here instead: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Setting+Up+the+Issues+Service

Comment: And now here: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Set+up+the+Issues+hook

Comment: If you enabled an issue tracker on your repository after August 2012, the Issue hook is enabled automatically for you.

Answer (score 8):

Redmine has configurable options. Most used ones are:

- Refs #XXX / See #XXX -- references an issue
- Closes #XXX / Fixes #XXX -- marks issue as resolved/closed

Comment: great! i loved the tool! Is there any hosted Redmine solution?

Comment: I believe redmine itself provides somewhat of a hosting solutions. Not sure though.

Comment: I haven't found anything about it in their site

Answer (score 3):

Trac does it as well, of course. It's easily configurable:

```
   _supported_cmds = {
                       'closed':     '_cmdClose',
                       'fix':        '_cmdClose',
                       'addresses':  '_cmdRefs',
                       're':         '_cmdRefs',
```