# How to close bitbucket task in a pull request comment via commit message?

Tags: git, workflow, bitbucket, issue-tracking

We work we bitbucket for a git version control system.

When doing a code review, one can create a task. Is it possible to close a task from a commit message? Or is it something that bitbucket doesn't provide?

I used to work with github, and there it was possible to [reference and close issues via commit messages](https://help.github.com/enterprise/11.10.340/user/articles/closing-issues-via-commit-messages/).

Comment: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/BITBUCKET/Resolve+issues+automatically+when+users+push+code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004177/how-to-mark-an-issue-as-resolved-from-the-commit-log

Comment: @Ôrel This helped, thanks! Maybe post it as an answer?

Comment: @KarlHorky done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Atleassian's documentation](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html), you can use a keyword and the task id to close it directly.

Statements that can be used within the commit message are:

```
close #845
fix bug #89
fixes issue #746
resolving #3117
```

Answer (score 1):

Effectively you cannot close pull requests tasks via commit message.

It seems that Bitbucket distinguishes issues from pull request tasks. If you are looking for ways of closing issues via commit message, take a look at Ôrel answer.